# Regex to get content between two patterns

Tags: swift, regex

I'm trying to (and stumbling) write a regex that would get all the content between two patterns:

So, the patterns are like so:

```
/SOMEWORD:
  Lots of content
/ANOTHERWORD:
```

So the pattern is forwardslash, word, colon. And I want to retrieve everything in between (including new lines)

I'm just learning regex and this is a little above my skill set.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Please show what you tried. That will provide an idea of your environment and of yourlevel of understanding. Ideally provide a [mre] and describe how it does not satisfy you. A good MRE contains several examples of matching and non-matching input.

Comment: @MonkeySuess - Swift. For iOS.

Comment: @PruitIgoe See my updated answer.

Comment: Do you must use a regex? String manipulation functions can work as well.

Answer (score -1):

This might work if Swift regex supports `\K`:

```
\/[^\r\n]+?:\K.*?(?=\/[^\r\n]+?:)
```

Just make sure the "single line" or "DOTALL" modifier is enabled; `/s`

https://regex101.com/r/6cNbck/1

Comment: Thanks, I should have been a little clearer, I don't know what the words will be. How would I do it with say a wildcard between / and :?

Comment: @PruitIgoe Not with my current example, no. The quantifier `*` cannot be used in lookbehinds unless you are using the .NET flavor of regex. Even then it would be more appropriate to use `/[^\r\n]+?:`